# Live update inbox messages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I need a suggestion with live update messages, here is my code:

```
<script>
    function fetch_messages(){
        var user_id = "1" // example id

        $.ajax({
            url: "do_fetch.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { user_id : user_id },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $("#messages_list").append('<div id="'+data.id+'">'+data.message+'</div>');
                }
                setTimeout("fetch_messages()", 3000);
            }
        });
    }
    $(function(){
        fetch_messages();
    });
</script>
```

and there is div messages:

```
<div id="messages">
</div>
```

php code:

```
<?php
    include('connection.php')

    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM messages WHERE user_id = '.mysql_real_escape_string($user_id).' AND my_id = '.mysql_real_escape_string($my_id);
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection);

    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

This code works, but I don't want to read all messages and show them, I need to load only new messages, so how should I do that? Do I need to put a hidden field with timestamp and to check with ajax for time later than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you load with ajax just 20 messages in a ul

```
<ul>
  <li>message 1</li>
  <li>message 2</li>
  <li>message 3</li>
  <li>message 4</li>
  <li>message 5</li>
  <li id="{{message_date}}">message 6</li>
</ul>
```

Then get the last message id to get the date.

```
$('li').last().attr('id')
```

you can have a click button to load more.

```
var message_date = $('li').last().attr('id');
$.ajax({
    url: "do_fetch.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { date : message_date },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $("ul").append('<liid="'+ data.date+'">'+data.message+'</li>');
        }
    }
});
```

In the php file you select the messages with date > message_date with limit 30.

You can pass the user id too.

Answer (score 2):

Save the id of the last message sent and then send that id via ajax, and query everything from newer than that id.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a "read" boolean field to your table. It should default to false, and then whenever messages are viewed, you should update all viewed messages to be read.

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE user_id=? AND my_id=? AND `read`=0;
UPDATE `messages` SET `read`=1 WHERE user_id=? AND my_id=?;
```

Comment: Thanks, i think that this is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use , for example, next:  setInterval(fetch_messages,5000)  . Every five sec will sending request. Than on server save in session  current time ( for first time ). During second request get from session last time, than  get current time  and fetch all rows between current and last time.